How to make React SPA crawlable and SEO friendly?
Issue / Objective:
We Want to make our React SPA application with dynamic pages
SEO friendly and crawlable
Technology used:

React JS SPA
PHP for SSR
React Helmet for Meta tag

Details of application:
We have ecommerce application which works dynamically for clients.
We have used SSR to render meta tags using PHP along with React
Application developed in React, we are using Helmet for rendering meta tags.
Suggested Solution:
Most of the people suggesting Next.js but to shift the application at this moment is very difficult , suggest any alternatives within framework of React and SSR PHP.

Helmet is great for social media sharing but meta tags have almost no impact on SEO. For SEO, SSR should render the whole page, not just the meta tags.
Google and Bing render JavaScript and index the rendered version of the page these days.  So you don't have to have full SSR for SEO.  But relying on search engines to render pages causes indexing delays and comes with a whole set of gotchas.  See my answer to  Do search engines perform JS rendering while crawling?
As far as implementing full SSR is concerned, React 18 supports server side rendering with the ReactDOMServer.renderToPipeableStream server API.  You can run node.js on a server to render your React pages. See How to implement SSR (Server Side Rendering) in React 18 | Simform Engineering

In all blogs every one suggesting next.js is the option , does React JS has flexibility to implement advanced SEO ? to support ecommerce platform.

There are huge websites with strong SEO that are now rending pages or parts of pages with React. I don't have enough personal experience with it that I can personally endorse it, nor enough to give you a recommendation between it and Next.js.  But from my outside perspective, I see is used in some key areas and it looks like it has all the pieces so that you can implement the features you need for SEO.
